# MongoDB - get $max among fields at different levels

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with documents of this (simplified) form

```
{
    "_id": "Doc"
    "created": NumberLong("1422526079335")
}
```

Additionally, this documents may have an additional `edited` field

```
{
    "_id": "Doc"
    "created": NumberLong("1422526079335")
    "edited": {
        "date": NumberLong("1458128507498")
    }
}
```

What I need is to get the most recent timestamp (among `created` and `edited.date`) for a subset of these documents, matching certain conditions.

What I achieved so far is to get the most recent `created` timestamp

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([ { $match: { ... } },
                            { $project: { _id:0, created: 1 } },
                            { $group: { _id: 'latest', latest: { $max: '$created' } } }
                          ])
```

which returns

```
{ "_id" : "latest", "latest" : NumberLong("1422526079335") }
```

How can I integrate the check against `edited.date` in the `$max` logic above? Or alternatively is there another solution? Thanks is advance!

Comment: since the `latest` is the time you requirement, why check it again in the `$max`? confused with your question...

Comment: just to clarify your question: if edited exists then you want to get edited value else just created value? is that right? can edited have more than one entry?

Comment: IIUC your query should return `NumberLong("1458128507498")` as maximum value if the `edited.date` field is present and `created` if it's not. Right?

Comment: You guys are correct: there's only one `date` field in `edited`, and in my case `edited.date` should be preferred, if present.
But, just for the sake of learning, I'd like to ask the solution assuming the 2 fields are not related in any way (basically the title of this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this script. it's simple `$max` operator.

I have following documents in collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Doc", 
    "created" : NumberLong(1422526079335), 
    "edited" : {
        "date" : NumberLong(1458128507498)
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Doc1", 
    "created" : NumberLong(1422526079335)
}
```

Try running following query:

```
db.doc.aggregate([
  { 
     $match: { ... } 
  },
  {
     $project:{
       latest:{ $max:["$created", "$edited.date"]}
     }
  }
])
```

Output will be:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Doc", 
    "latest" : NumberLong(1458128507498)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Doc1", 
    "latest" : NumberLong(1422526079335)
}
```

Comment: nice example of $max!

Comment: Ah, it was so straight ahead!
I'm accepting this as answer as I think it complies the most to my question, however thanks to @profesor79 for his solution too! I just learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use $cond in last $project pipe - **lastModifedDate** makes the trick :-)

```
db.ill.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        lastModifedDate:{
              $cond: { 
                 if: { $gte: [ "$created", "$edited.date"] }, 
                 then: "$created", else: "$edited.date" }
        }}}])
```